# Edge: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

My page works fine in Chrome and Firefox:
[image]

However, when I try to load this page in Edge, the questions and answers disappear. Only the categories are posted. Also, when trying to load this page in IE, everything disappears except for the search bar.

Edge gives me the following error:

> SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number on line 84 of faq.html

This refers to the following code:

```
function sortByCategory(data) {
  return data.reduce((obj, c) => {
    const { category, ...rest } = c; // this line throws the error
    obj[category] = obj[category] || [];
    obj[category].push(rest);
    return obj;
  }, {});
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It appears (surprisingly) that Edge doesn't support property rest yet, which is unfortunate but then it was officially added only in ES2018. You'll need to rewrite the code not to use property rest (the `...rest` part of your object literal) (or, as [CertainPerformance suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53628253/157247), use a transpiler).

Here's *one* of many ways to do that:

```
function sortByCategory(data) {
    return data.reduce((obj, c) => {
        //const { category, ...rest } = c;
        const { category } = c;
        const rest = {};
        for (const key of Object.keys(c)) {
            if (key !== "category") {
                rest[key] = c[key];
            }
        }
        obj[category] = obj[category] || [];
        obj[category].push(rest);
        return obj;
    }, {});
}
```

I avoided using `delete` because `delete` on an object de-optimizes the object, making property lookups slower. But deoptimizing just these objects may well not make any difference to the perceived speed of your page/app, so...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Works flawlessly, thanks.

Comment: plus one for native suggestions

Comment: I've just tested in [Edge Chromium Beta 78.0.276.19](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download), the  `...` syntax in object spread on the *right* side of an assignment `a = {...b, ...c};` This works. (It broke in Edge 18 with the same syntax message as this question.) I haven't tested it on *left* side of an assignment yet, as in this question, but it should work there also, given that this is V8 JavaScript from Chromium project. Another of my web pages, that doesn't work in either Edge 18 or Safari 13 (without shims/transpilation), works flawlessly in this Beta.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - Thanks. Yes, Edge Chromium will presumably have full rest and spread support (including property rest and spread), because it uses V8, which has full rest and spread support.

Answer (score 9):

Neither Edge nor IE [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility) object property rest syntax (though Edge will likely support it eventually). I'd suggest automatically transpiling your code to ES5 with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/), which will allow you to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, while allowing ancient and incompatible browsers to understand all of your transpiled code. For example, plugging in

```
const { category, ...rest } = c;
```

results in

```
"use strict";

function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) { var target = {}; for (var i in obj) { if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue; target[i] = obj[i]; } return target; }

var _c = c,
    category = _c.category,
    rest = _objectWithoutProperties(_c, ["category"]);
```

Doesn't look so pretty, but it can be done automatically.

One manual way of doing it could be:

```js
const c = {
  category: 'category',
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
};

const category = c.category;
// Object.assign so as not to mutate the original object:
const rest = Object.assign({}, c);
delete rest.category;
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: Good answer! Probably worth removing "IE" from that "yet" sentence. :-) IE will never support it (or anything else ES2015+).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even know about Babel, oops

Comment: Also, considering [Edge will likely be replaced by a chromium variant](https://www.theverge.com/2018/12/4/18125238/microsoft-chrome-browser-windows-10-edge-chromium), the browser should be more inline with at least Chrome. (Whether this is a good or bad thing for the browser market and the standards, I'll leave in the middle.)

Comment: @BramVanroy - It's unclear whether they're building on *Chromium*, which is a browser built on a stack of several components, or just *Blink*, the rendering engine in it (and Chrome, and Opera). Sadly, reporting on this topic has conflated the two. I *think* they're just replacing the rendering engine. From the article you linked: *"Adopting Chromium as the default rendering engine..."* If they keep Chakra (their JavaScript engine), the change wouldn't affect their support for JavaScript features. That said, they're happy to use V8 (Google's JS engine) via Electron in VS Code, so...we'll see!

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020-05-12 this will work in Microsoft Edge. Tested version: `Microsoft Edge Version 81.0.416.72 (Official build) (64-bit)`

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

The following lines of code caused the exception `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number` but when updating everything worked:

```
return {
    ...state,
    products: [...state.products, ...action.payload],
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this new update to Chromium Edge is not delivered in app, so users need to know of it and then manually install... not easy for common users

Answer (score 2):

In case you have node package ecosystem:

1. Update browser list in your package.json

```js
{
  ...
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ...
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "last 1 ie version" // <- make sure this is present
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

2. Delete .cache folder in node_modules
3. Re-run the dev server

Answer (score 1):

Edge 44 fails with "SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number" with :

```js
var a = {};
a = { ...a};
```

But succeeded with:

```
var a = {};
a = Object.assign({}, a);
```