# operator ..props not working on Microsoft Edge [ 41.16299.1480.0 ]

Tags: node.js, angular, babeljs, microsoft-edge, polyfills

starting from this discussion [Edge: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628191/edge-script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number) I didn't get how to fix the problem using babel.
The problem I am facing is inside a module (not my class) that I am using, so I can't make patches on the code (easily).

I am importing a class that:

```
import { Class1 } from '@eds/vanilla';   <-- This is not mine

that his then importing another class 

./src/public/eds-components/charts/bar-charts/Class1.js

That is importing :
import { ColorScale } from '../common/ColorScale';


export class ColorScale {

  /**
   * Setup color scale properties
   * @param {Object} props - The properties to initialize the color scale
   * @param {Array} props.colors - The array of colors
   */
  constructor(props) {
    props = {
      ...props
    };
    this.length = props.length || 15;
    this.colors = props.colors || this.generateColorMatrix(this.length);
  }
```

How can I use babel/polyfills or whatever to fix the problem on a module that is not under my control?

It seems there are problems on *pre-build-optimizer* phase.. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` plugin.

Use the following command to install this plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
```

Then,refer to the following methods to use it:

- With a configuration file (Recommended)

  ```
  {
     "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
  }
  ```
- Via CLI

  ```
  babel --plugins @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread script.js
  ```

More detail information, please check [this link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread).