# create a html table with json response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have created a table with JSON response with is working perfectly in chrome and firefox but not working in Edge. What to change for browser compatibility. Not working for the edge version

[image]

getting error as  `SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number` in the line `...Object.fromEntries`

```js
const summary_data = [{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:2},{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Closed Won",count:8},{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:16},{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Qualified",count:3},{Geo:"US East",SalesStage:"Identified",count:50},{Geo:"US West",SalesStage:"Identified",count:39},{Geo:"NSU",SalesStage:"Identified",count:20}];

// Gather the headers we'll have in the end table
const stages = summary_data.reduce((res, row) => {
  if (!res.includes(row.SalesStage)) res.push(row.SalesStage);
  return res;
}, []).concat('Total'); // ["Closed Won", "Qualified", "Identified", "Total"]

// Gather every field for each Geo
const obj = summary_data.reduce((res, row) => {
  if (!res[row.Geo]) {
    res[row.Geo] = Object.fromEntries([ ['Geo', row.Geo], ...stages.map(s => [s, 0]) ]);
  }
  res[row.Geo][row.SalesStage] += row.count;
  res[row.Geo].Total += row.count;
  return res;
}, {}); // { "US West": {}, "US East": {}, ... }

const data = Object.values(obj); // [ { "Geo": "US West", "Closed Won": 2, ...}, ...]

// Add a "Total" row
data.push({
  Geo: 'Total',
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    stages.map(s => [s, data.reduce((sum, row) => row[s] + sum, 0)])
  )
});

$('thead').append(
  Object.keys(data[0]).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
);
$('tbody').append(
  data.map(row => $('<tr>').append(
     Object.values(row).map(x => $('<td>').text(x))
  ))
);
```

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse}td{border:1px solid #000;padding:.5em}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> <thead> </thead> <tbody> </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edge: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628191/edge-script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number)

Comment: did you checked edge console to validate it

Comment: ya getting error in the line ...Object.fromEntries